# Ripple20 Vulnerabilities in Linux Kernel

Tags: linux, debian, networking

During one of my security assessment of a Linux based product, I came across Ripple20 Vulnerability. I got to know that the issue lies in Treck a TCP-IP library. Can any one tell us whether Debian Buster having Linux kernel 4.19 is vulnerable to such issue ?

Answer (score 4):

No, Ripple20 specifically concerns the Treck TCP/IP stack, which isn’t used in the Linux kernel.

Comment: Are there any supporting documents that support this statement?

Comment: @Anand what are you looking for? There isn’t a list of all the TCP/IP stacks which aren’t used in the kernel. [The Ripple20 vulnerabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ripple20) are specifically vulnerabilities in [the Treck stacks](https://treck.com/vulnerability-response-information/) which are proprietary.